# How to read unknown data length in a TCP Client

Tags: c#, tcp, arrays, tcpclient

I am relativity new to C#. In my TCP client have the following function which sends data to the server and returns the response:

```
private static TcpClient tcpint = new TcpClient(); //Already initiated and set up
private static NetworkStream stm;                  //Already initiated and set up

private static String send(String data)
{
    //Send data to the server
    ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
    byte[] ba = asen.GetBytes(data);
    stm.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);

    //Read data from the server
    byte[] bb = new byte[100];
    int k = stm.Read(bb, 0, 100);

    //Construct the response from byte array to string
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(bb[i].ToString());
    }

    //Return server response
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

As you can see here, when I am reading the response from the server, I am reading it into a fix byte[] array of length 100 bytes.

```
byte[] bb = new byte[100];
int k = stm.Read(bb, 0, 100);
```

What do i do if the response from the server is more than 100 bytes? How can I read the data without me knowing what the max length of data form the server will be?

Comment: You can send the data length before sending the data, or use a seperator char which doesn't exist in the data

Comment: @L.B Oh ok, that kinda makes sense. So I would have two read operation. First one would get the data length. Second will get that actual data based on the length given in the first read operation. Right?

Comment: But, if your string doesn't contain newline char, using `var reader = new StreamReader(tcpint.GetStream());` would be easier ( and also `StreamWriter` at other side). that way, you only have to do is `reader.ReadLine()` or `writer.WriteLine()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, where there is not some specific intrinsic size of something, tcp protocols explicitly send the length of objects they are sending.  One possible method for illustration:

```
size_t data_len = strlen(some_data_blob);
char lenstr[32];
sprintf(lenstr, "%zd\n", data_len);
send(socket, lenstr, strlen(lenstr));
send(socket, some_data_blob, data_len);
```

then when the receiver reads the length string, it knows exactly how mush data *should* follow (good programming practice is to *trust but verify* though -- if there is more or less data really sent -- say by an *'evil actor'* -- you need to be prepared to handle that).

Comment: Awesome! Makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 1):

Not with respect to C# but a general answer on writing TCP application:

TCP is stream based protocol. It does not maintain message boundaries. So, the applications using TCP should take care of choosing the right method of data exchange between server and client. Its becomes more paramount if multiple messages gets sent and received on one connection.

One widely used method is to prepend the data message with the length bytes.

Ex:

`[2 byte -length field][Actual Data]`.

The receiver of such data (be it server or client needs to decode length field, wait for until such event where as many bytes are received or raise an alarm on timeout and give up.

Another protocol that can be used is to have applications maintain message boundaries.

Ex:
`[START-of-MSG][Actual Data][END-of-MSG]

The reciever has to parse the data for Start-byte and End-byte (predefined by application protocol) and treat anything in between as data of interest.

Answer (score 1):

hello i solved it with a list, i don't know the size of the complete package but i can read it in parts

```
List<byte> bigbuffer = new List<byte>();

byte[] tempbuffer = new byte[254]; 
//can be in another size like 1024 etc.. 
//depend of the data as you sending from de client
//i recommend small size for the correct read of the package

NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

while (stream.Read(tempbuffer, 0, tempbuffer.Length) > 0) {

    bigbuffer.AddRange(tempbuffer);
} 

// now you can convert to a native byte array
byte[] completedbuffer = new byte[bigbuffer.Count];

bigbuffer.CopyTo(completedbuffer);

//Do something with the data
string decodedmsg = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(completedbuffer);
```

I do this whith images and looks good, i thik than you dont know the size of the data if the porpouse is read a complete source with a unknow size

Comment: o can ReceiveBufferSize property of tcpclient object

Answer (score 0):

I was looking around for an answer to this, and noticed the Available property was added to TcpClient. It returns the amount of bytes available to read.

I'm assuming it was added after most of the replies, so I wanted to share it for others that may stumble onto this question.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.available?view=netframework-4.8